# Run a CTE on multiple input values

Tags: sql, recursion, common-table-expression

In the article "[Simple Recursion in SQL with Common Table Expressions](http://douglaskline.blogspot.co.za/2016/06/simple-recursion-in-sql-with-common.html)", **Douglas Kline** shows how one can recursively query `"Boss of"` a given `Employee` in an Employee table.

For example I can use the following query to obtain the recursive list of employees for Employee with ID 16:

```
WITH EmployeeAndTheirBosses 
  (EmployeeID,
  LastName,
  ReportsTo,
  BossLastName,
  depth)
AS
(
SELECT  EmployeeID,
        LastName,
        ReportsTo,
        LastName,
        0 
FROM    Employee
WHERE   EmployeeID = 16

UNION ALL 

SELECT   Employee.EmployeeID,
         Employee.LastName,
         Employee.ReportsTo,
         EmployeeAndTheirBosses.LastName,
         EmployeeAndTheirBosses.depth + 1
FROM     Employee
   JOIN  EmployeeAndTheirBosses ON Employee.EmployeeID = EmployeeAndTheirBosses.ReportsTo
)

SELECT   *
FROM     EmployeeAndTheirBosses
ORDER BY depth
```

This will return:

```
16, ReportsTo 6,
6, ReportsTo 2,
2, ReportsTo null.
```

How can I query multiple `EmployeeID` values in the same query, and results would be listed one after the other?

E.g. The WHERE clause in the first SELECT would be something like:

```
WHERE EmployeeID in (16, 34)
```

and the results would be:

```
34, ReportsTo 5,
5, ReportsTo 2,
2, ReportsTo null.
16, ReportsTo 6,
6, ReportsTo 2,
2, ReportsTo null.
```

**EDIT**:

Ok, based on Gordon's answer, I have come up with the following query. What I found strange was using the same column name twice in the first select statement..

```
WITH EmployeeAndTheirBosses 
  (OrigID,
  EmployeeID,
  LastName,
  ReportsTo,
  BossLastName,
  depth)
AS
(
SELECT  EmployeeID,
        EmployeeID,
        LastName,
        ReportsTo,
        LastName,
        0 
FROM    Employee
WHERE   EmployeeID in (16, 34)

UNION ALL 

SELECT   EmployeeAndTheirBosses.OrigID,
         Employee.EmployeeID,
         Employee.LastName,
         Employee.ReportsTo,
         EmployeeAndTheirBosses.LastName,
         EmployeeAndTheirBosses.depth + 1
FROM     Employee
   JOIN  EmployeeAndTheirBosses ON Employee.EmployeeID = EmployeeAndTheirBosses.ReportsTo
)

SELECT   *
FROM     EmployeeAndTheirBosses
ORDER BY OrigID, depth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The results are not "interleaved".  The results are *arbitrary*.  Without an `order by` clause, SQL can return the result set in any order.  Even running the same query twice on the same data can produce different orderings.

You need to include the original employee id in the CTE and then use an `order by` in the outer query:

```
order by originalEmployeeId, depth
```

Comment: How do I include the originalEmployeeId in each record of the CTE?

Comment: @RaelB . . . I thought the article was a good article ;)  You include it as an additional column in the first part and then include it in the second part as well.